# Kaminari wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari, argument-error

I'm using kaminari and bootstrap_kaminari gems in my app. Previously they worked fine, but now, I don't know if it was an update that I made, this error appears every time the method `paginate` is called:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments(0 for 1)):
7: -#    per_page:      number of items to fetch per page
8: -#    remote:        data-remote
9: %li{:class => "page#{' active' if page.current?}"}
10:   = link_to page, page.current? ? "#" : url, {:remote => remote, :method => method, :rel => page.next? ? 'next' : page.prev? ? 'prev' : nil}
app/views/kaminari/bootstrap/_page.html.haml:10:in `method'
app/views/kaminari/bootstrap/_page.html.haml:10:in `_app_views_kaminari_bootstrap__page_html_haml___4572733049493505448_70240978127920'
app/views/kaminari/bootstrap/_paginator.html.haml:14:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_kaminari_bootstrap__paginator_html_haml__2289167586420570675_70240961152960'
app/views/kaminari/bootstrap/_paginator.html.haml:12:in `block in _app_views_kaminari_bootstrap__paginator_html_haml__2289167586420570675_70240961152960'
app/views/kaminari/bootstrap/_paginator.html.haml:8:in `_app_views_kaminari_bootstrap__paginator_html_haml__2289167586420570675_70240961152960'
app/views/network/_job_offer_results.html.erb:74:in `_app_views_network__job_offer_results_html_erb___3561074850404149034_70240933051920'
app/views/network/job_offer_home.html.erb:60:in `_app_views_network_job_offer_home_html_erb___1400061891974561937_70240932539240'
```

I have no idea which method is supposed to take 1 argument but is taking 0. `page.current?`, `page.next?` or `page.prev?`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Break that line into three, one for each method, and see what it gives you.

Comment: Apparently it's `page.next?`. But this view was generated by kaminari. It wasn't supposed to be broken like this...

Comment: Stop using bootstrap_kaminari and do `rails g kaminari:views bootstrap`. Also read my blog post about the integration of kaminari and bootstrap: http://yukinishijima.net/post/34172737927